# Laravel 5 RESTful resource route not working

Tags: php, rest, routes, laravel-5

I have Laravel 5 resource route:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {

    Route::resource('api/room', 'RoomsController');

    // ...
});
```

The `RoomsController` is generated with `php artisan make:controller` command.

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Auth;
use App\Room;
use App\RoomUsers;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class RoomsController extends Controller {
    // ...
}
```

The `index` route **working**. When I `GET` the `api/room`, It returns expected result.
There is the `RoomsController@index` method:

```
public function index() {
    $user = Auth::user();
    $currentUserRooms = RoomUsers::where('user_id', '=', $user->id)->get();
    return response($currentUserRooms);
}
```

**The problem**:
When I try to `POST` to the same URI (`/api/room`), I get **500 Internal Server Error**.

There is the `RoomsController@store` method (which should be called when `POST` request coming).

```
public function store() {
    return response('is Working') // But isn't working
}
```

I setted these options in the php.ini file, but I still can't see the error information. It shows only "500 Internal server error"

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
```

I have enabled the Laravel 5 debug mode too.

Comment: What specific error are you receiving when you post to that route?

Comment: "500 Internal server error" I enabled `error_reporting` and `display_error`, but no more information about the error is showed.

Comment: Is your 'app.debug' option set to true? Edit: just saw the last line. Well you can't be seeing only the 500 error, either your server logs or the application logs *must* have the exact error specified, you have to find it.

Comment: Yes, But I think isn't laravel error, cuz isn't showing stack trace. Just I am not very familiar with PHP and debugging and I get stuck.

Comment: I just noticed something, you defined the controller's starting point as `api/rooms`, but further down you say that you're trying to POST to `api/routes` - is that a typo?

Comment: @KaloyanDoichinov Yes it's typo. I see this is not clear error. I'll try to make other resource routes and somethings to test why and when this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by Laravel's CSRF Protection.

I used **PostMan** to send the requests. It accepts `GET` requests, but not `POST` or `PUT`.

I used the fix from [this page](http://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/disable-csrf-on-specific-routes) to disable CSRF to these routes :

```
// app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php
// ...
class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier {

    private $openRoutes = ['api/room', 'api/message'];

    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        foreach ($this->openRoutes as $route) {
            if ($request->is($route)) {
                return $next($request);
            }
        }

        return parent::handle($request, $next);
    }
}
```

**About the error reporting**:
Yesterday I enabled all error reporting options and restarted many times the *apache2* service. But no error description or stack trace was showed in *PostMan*.

Today I wake up and tested it. It just worked. Now I have laravel error reporting with stack trace. I didn't turned off or restart the machine. (Lubuntu 14.04 32bit).
I have no idea why this was happen yesterday. Maybe it was some stupid bug.

Comment: Instead of disabling CSRF you should have added the token to POST headers.How do you post the data? Javascript?

Answer (score 2):

I tried the code. and it worked. Make sure you are logged.
[image: RoomsController]

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was caused by CSRF Protection.